# get / set functions and inlining

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, inline

My question is pretty simple:
**Q:** Do `get` and `set` functions have an increased chance of being inlined compared to standard functions?

If so, is there anything that prevents me from using them for something other than their intended use? (Other than my code becoming less readable.)

Comment: Inlining is supposed to be transparent with respect to semantics. Does that answer the second part of your question? (Are you trying to use them to attempt to inline stuff?)

Comment: As far as I know, function inlining isn't supported at all with AS3 -- is there something I'm missing? [HaXe](http://haxe.org) supports (really good) inlining, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, Flash very rarely inlines anything. I am almost positive it doesn't even happen for getters and setters as you can still acccess them by reflection (which shouldn't be possible for inlined definitions). I would certainly not use them in the effort to improve performance. If you really really want those gains, use Haxe instead as you can do true inline function definitions with the Flash runtime with it.
Hope this helps!

Comment: As far as I understand, flash has a JIT compiler and it can indeed inline functions. (Similar to Java's JIT)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know this for certain, but i would expect the answer to be no. Many elements in flash are dynamic, and the flash compiler is notorious for not making bytecode optimizations.

In practice I know that using getters, setters are slower than using function calls, and that function calls are slower than directly accessing public variables.

If you want to inline a function in actionscript, the best practice is terrible: copy the dang code. 
So obviously that is a last phase of optimization after all the bugs are worked out.

edit:
There is an open source bytecode optimizer from Joa ebert that can make many improvements on Adobe compiled swfs. https://github.com/joa/apparat
Read up there. Scroll own in the Readme to look at tools. What you want is called TDSI - TurboDeiselSportInjection. How's that for a name?